# WDS + MDT How to avoid pxe boot loop

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, mdt

I am trying to automate the reimage process for our SuperMicro servers.
Generally, i want to achive the situation from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831764(v=ws.11)

> Ron configures Windows Deployment Services so when a computer is
>   restarted, it will boot from the network automatically and deploy the
>   appropriate image **(without requiring the users to press F12). He also
>   configures the deployment so that when the computer restarts, the
>   computer will not network boot unless F12 is pressed.** This way, the
>   computer then boots to the hard disk drive and finishes the
>   installation process. This prevents a boot loop, in which the computer
>   would continue booting into Setup.

So my default server settings is *"Require the user to press F12 key to PXE boot"* for both known and unknown clients.

I prestaged computer account in AD with default boot program *pxeboot.n12* and executed command *wdsutil /set-server /resetbootprogram:yes*

Server booted from PXE without F12 and started MDT deployment correctly. But after restart he again booted from PXE although he had to reset boot program to the default server settings.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: There is an option in the WDS server properties that allows you to change the f12 settings.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known MDT issue with LTIApply.wsf file. It needs to be manually changed to correct the network boot loop.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/849483/mdt-v-8443-adk-v-1703-boot-order-changed-after-post-install-using-uefi